# DataBinding to a TextBox not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am having a difficult time getting my WPF to properly use Databinding. In the XAML I have a the following:

```
....
<TextBox Name="txt_FirstName" Text="{Binding Path=currentApplication.FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
....
```

I have in the following CS code:

```
namespace WPF1
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    personalApp currentApplication = new personalApp ();

    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

  }
}
```

That references the following two classes:

```
class personalApp : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private Person person = new Person();

  public string FirstName
  {
    get { return person.FirstName; }
    set
    {
      person.FirstName = value;
      this.OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
  {
    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
      this.PropertyChanged(
      this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
   }

}

class Person
{
  private string firstName = "";

  get { return firstName; }
  set { FirstName = value; }
}
```

I pause it in the code and step through to check, but when I update the txt_FirstName in the application, it never seems to set the firstName Object.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update your `XAML` binding, and set the `DataContext` of the Window using the `TextBox`.

```
namespace WPF1
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    personalApp currentApplication = new personalApp ();

    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.DataContext = currentApplication;
    }
  }
}
```

Updating the XAML:

```
<TextBox Name="txt_FirstName" Text="{Binding FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I have corrected the code.

For text box:

```
<TextBox Name="txt_FirstName" Height="30" Background="Beige"
             Text="{Binding Path=FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

C# Code

```
namespace Wpf1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new personalApp();
    }
}

internal class personalApp : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Person person = new Person();

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return person.FirstName; }
        set
        {
            person.FirstName = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(
            this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}

internal class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public MainWindow()
{
  DataContext = this;
  InitializeComponent();
}
```

or if you don't want to assign data context to yourself (window), as you might have other datacontext coming into the window, you can add this in xaml:
give your window a name:

```
<Window .... x:Name="this"...
```

then

```
<TextBox Name="txt_FirstName" Text="{Binding ElementName=this,
                                     Path=currentApplication.FirstName/>
```

Answer (score -1):

What you mean by "update the txt_FirstName in the application" ?
If you set directly the value of the textbox then you should try to set the value of `currentApplication` instead of the textbox value